# How to define multiple range clauses in WindowSpec?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

In SparkSQL it is possible to define a window query with 2+ order by columns, but it doesn't seem to be possible to define range clauses based on those columns.

For example,

```
select
row_id,
count(*) over (
    partition by group_id
    order by filter_key1, filter_key2
    range between 12 preceding and 12 following
    range between 5 preceding and 1 preceding
) as the_count
from table
```

The above fails (though perhaps the syntax is off? fingers crossed...)

Can it be done in a single statement similar to the above?

Answer (score 0):

No, only one range is allowed.  But don't despair.  `count(*)` is additive:

```
select row_id,
       (count(*) over (partition by group_id
                       order by filter_key1, filter_key2
                       range between 12 preceding and 12 following
                      ) +
        count(*) over (partition by group_id
                       order by filter_key1, filter_key2
                       range between 5 preceding and 1 preceding
                      )
       ) as the_count
from table
```

This particular example seems curious, because the ranges are overlapping.  Perhaps that is your intention.

Based on your question, I wonder if you want:

```
select row_id,
       (count(*) over (partition by group_id
                       order by filter_key1
                       range between 12 preceding and 12 following
                      ) +
        count(*) over (partition by group_id
                       order by filter_key2
                       range between 5 preceding and 1 preceding
                      )
       ) as the_count
from table
```

Comment: The intent is to aggregate over a range of time that truncates the start down to the beginning of the day and keeps the end at the preceding record. So, a little awkward because I want to get the intersection between the two filters. Restated, I want all records from N days back (starting at 00:00) up to just until the current time (which might be in the middle of the day).

Comment: Your second example would be great if the data were disjoint.

Comment: @taw . . . You should ask another question with sample data and desired results.  This question seems quite different from what you are looking for.